# Failed to acquire lock on file .lock

Tags: apache-kafka

Trying Kafka for the first time, following the steps in the official documentation http://kafka.apache.org/documentation. 
Everything works fine until I try to set up multiple brokers, (this step: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_multibroker) once I try to start the other 2 servers I get the "Failed to acquire lock on file .lock in C:/tmp/kafka-logs"

Things Ive done:

1. restarted machine
2. erased the directory C:/tmp/kafka-logs and ran it again
3. I changed the log.dir= to a different folder for each broker, that
   gave unexpected results.
4. Of course I changed settings for the serverxx.properties so the broker.id is different in each, and the listeners=plaintext://:909X

just trying to understand what Im doing wrong. thanks in advance guys/gals!

Comment: "I changed the log.dir= to a different folder for each broker, that gave unexpected results."  ---- What unexpected results did you get?

Comment: You should not have multiple brokers on the same machine...

Comment: Hey Matthias, I was just following along the Apache getting started guide. is it convention to not have the different brokers on the same machine?

amesthystic, only the leader broker was 'saving' the test messages, once I closed the leader, instead of switching to the other brokers it just failed.

Comment: You have to set different log directories for different brokers if they all reside on a same machine. As for your second question, it's probably because the topic you created is with a replication factor of 1, so there are no other replicas.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Will try the replication factor of 3 once I change the log.dir for the 3 different brokers. Thanks amethystic